# Three.js - group objects with clipping capabilities (masking)

Tags: javascript, three.js, mask, clipping

Im trying to group objects with clipping capabilities (masking), this is my code (the group definition part):

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100, 1, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({transparent: true});

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
editor.addObject(mesh);
editor.select(mesh);
```

EXPLANATION: basically what im trying to do is this - 
Define a mesh as a group ("parent") of objects ("children") with masking capabilities: all children of the parent are visible only if they are in the borders of the "parent" object group. the other object's visibility should not be affected by the "parent".

is there a simple way to go ?

Comment: This is a really vague query. Can you add a picture of what you want it to look like? What is the `editor` object?

Comment: thank you for the comment. please look at  the edited question